# How to add Tracing to IIS under Windows Server 2012 R2 under Azure

Tags: azure, iis, roles, trace

We are currently struggling to add Tracing to the roles on a Windows Server 2012 R2 under Azure. We have been working through [Avanti's](https://forums.ivanti.com/s/article/How-To-Enable-IIS-Failed-Request-Tracing) description of the procedure but consistently encounter a failure about 2/3 of the way through. We get to the screen that says "Feature installation" of "Web Server (IIS) > Web Server > Health and Diagnostics > Tracing" only to have the following text appear:

> The request to add or remove features on the specified server failed. Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed. Error: 0x800f0922

A slightly redacted version of `DeploymentConfigTemplate.xml` is provided below in case it's meaningful:

```xml
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
    <Obj RefId="0">
        <TN RefId="0">
            <T>System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[System.Management.Automation.PSObject, System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]</T>
            <T>System.Object</T>
        </TN>
        <LST>
            <Obj RefId="1">
                <TN RefId="1">
                    <T>Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/ServerManager/ServerComponent_Web_Http_Tracing</T>
                    <T>Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/ServerManager/MSFT_ServerManagerServerComponentDescriptor</T>
                    <T>Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ServerComponent_Web_Http_Tracing</T>
                    <T>Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#MSFT_ServerManagerServerComponentDescriptor</T>
                    <T>Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance</T>
                    <T>System.Object</T>
                </TN>
                <ToString>ServerComponent_Web_Http_Tracing</ToString>
                <Props>
                    <S N="PSComputerName">SOME-COMPUTER-NAME</S>
                </Props>
                <MS>
                    <I32 N="NumericId">159</I32>
                    <Obj N="__ClassMetadata" RefId="2">
                        <TN RefId="2">
                            <T>System.Collections.ArrayList</T>
                            <T>System.Object</T>
                        </TN>
                        <LST>
                            <Obj RefId="3">
                                <MS>
                                    <S N="ClassName">MSFT_ServerManagerServerComponentDescriptor</S>
                                    <S N="Namespace">ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/ServerManager</S>
                                    <S N="ServerName">SOME-COMPUTER-NAME</S>
                                    <I32 N="Hash">1884695400</I32>
                                    <S N="MiXml">&lt;CLASS NAME="MSFT_ServerManagerServerComponentDescriptor"&gt;&lt;QUALIFIER NAME="dynamic" TYPE="boolean"&gt;&lt;VALUE&gt;true&lt;/VALUE&gt;&lt;/QUALIFIER&gt;&lt;QUALIFIER NAME="locale" TYPE="sint32" TOSUBCLASS="false"&gt;&lt;VALUE&gt;1033&lt;/VALUE&gt;&lt;/QUALIFIER&gt;&lt;QUALIFIER NAME="provider" TYPE="string"&gt;&lt;VALUE&gt;deploymentprovider&lt;/VALUE&gt;&lt;/QUALIFIER&gt;&lt;/CLASS&gt;</S>
                                </MS>
                            </Obj>
                            <Obj RefId="4">
                                <MS>
                                    <S N="ClassName">ServerComponent_Web_Http_Tracing</S>
                                    <S N="Namespace">ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/ServerManager</S>
                                    <S N="ServerName">SOME-COMPUTER-NAME</S>
                                    <I32 N="Hash">1983160024</I32>
                                    <S N="MiXml">&lt;CLASS NAME="ServerComponent_Web_Http_Tracing" SUPERCLASS="MSFT_ServerManagerServerComponentDescriptor"&gt;&lt;QUALIFIER NAME="dynamic" TYPE="boolean"&gt;&lt;VALUE&gt;true&lt;/VALUE&gt;&lt;/QUALIFIER&gt;&lt;QUALIFIER NAME="provider" TYPE="string"&gt;&lt;VALUE&gt;deploymentprovider&lt;/VALUE&gt;&lt;/QUALIFIER&gt;&lt;QUALIFIER NAME="ClassVersion" TYPE="string"&gt;&lt;VALUE&gt;0.0.0&lt;/VALUE&gt;&lt;/QUALIFIER&gt;&lt;QUALIFIER NAME="DisplayName" TYPE="string" TRANSLATABLE="true"&gt;&lt;VALUE&gt;Web-Http-Tracing&lt;/VALUE&gt;&lt;/QUALIFIER&gt;&lt;/CLASS&gt;</S>
                                </MS>
                            </Obj>
                        </LST>
                    </Obj>
                </MS>
            </Obj>
        </LST>
    </Obj>
</Objs>
```

We are working through as many of the [7 Ways to 0x800f0922 Windows 10 Error](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/0x800f0922-windows-10.html) as are applicable. Other suggestions welcome.

**LATER**

```
C:\bin>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some
of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For
example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note that logging is currently not
supported in offline servicing scenarios.
```

The CBS.log file is 5.3MB. Might try DISM next.

```
C:\bin>DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031

[==========================100.0%==========================]
No component store corruption detected.
The operation completed successfully.

C:\bin> DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031

[==========================100.0%==========================]
The restore operation completed successfully. The component store corruption was repaired.
The operation completed successfully.
```

**LATER STILL**

No. Still not installing. Ideas anyone?

Comment: 1) Do you have enough free space?, 2) Are you using an Antivirus?, 3) Any third-party programs or clean install?

Comment: (3) Azure-provisioned resource. (2) only what's provisioned by Azure. (1) Not sure how much is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being able to call in Support, we spent a few days generating and sending logs to a Microsoft support engineer, resulting in the following instructions:

```
... please create the folder C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles on your problematic machine. 
Then please right click this folder, choose Properties, then under Security tab, 
assign the following permissions:

System - Full Control
Administrators - Full Control 
IIS_IUSRS - List folder/read data, Create files/ write data, create folders/ append data, write attributes, write extend attributes, delete subfolders and files and delete.
```

This was sufficient to enable installation of the Tracing role. In the process, one particularly difficult and troubling 500 issue disappeared. So after all the hoo-hah and to-ing and fro-ing we have not had to use the FRT module after all.

Answer (score 1):

1)Make sure you have enough space in your machine.

2)Delete the contents of the Windows Temp folder (normally C:\Windows\Temp), and then again try to install the feature.

3)Turn off Firewall for both private and public networks.

4)Make sure you have the latest version of NET Framework installed.

5)Please run Windows Update troubleshooter on the Server 2012R2, check if it could fix the issues

6)Try to reinstall the Windows Process Activation Service.

7)Make sure you disable Shared Configuration when installing the IIS feature.

after doing all the things restart the machine and try again to install the feature.

Comment: Windows Update Troubleshooter has not been installed on this Azure-provisioned Windows Server 2012R2

Comment: (1) How much is enough. (2) Already done. (3) Why? (4) Can only go on what's provisioned. (5) See above. (6) Why? (7) Can't see where to turn on or off.

Comment: 3)some time firewalls or any antivirus cause the issue while you install any feature or software. 6)some feature cause the interruption for installation 7)open iis ->select server node-> double click shared configuration and uncheck the enable box if it is checked. [imgage](https://i.imgur.com/6xK3EnJ.png)

Comment: (7) Not checked

Comment: @bugmagnet  how many sites you have in your iis? you could try to reinstall iis

Comment: About 20. This is an Azure server. I was rather hoping not to have to consider such a thing.